# Конкатенация строк, обрезает часть строки

Tags: javascript

Есть строка

```
https://site.com/order/external/main.action?
```

К ней добавляю еще одну строку

```
shop=123456&transaction=123456&successUrl=http://site.ru/pay/success&failUrl=http://site.ru/pay/error&user=380999999999
```

В итоге получаю

```
https://site.com/order/external/main.action?shop=123456&transaction=123456&…ttp://site.ru/pay/error&failUrl=http://site.ru/pay/error&user=380999999999
```

Конкатенирую не важно как

```
str1.concat(str2);
```

или

```
str1+str2;
```

Думал обрезает по длине, сделал новую переменную длиной в 2 раза больше - её выводить целиком.

В чем проблема?

Comment: на самом деле результат верный, просто консоль браузера в которой просматривается результат _оптимизирует_ вывод

Answer (score 2, accepted):

на самом деле результат верный, просто консоль браузера в которой просматривается результат *оптимизирует* вывод

```js
var str1 = 'https://site.com/order/external/main.action?';

var str2 = 'shop=123456&transaction=123456&successUrl=http://site.ru/pay/success&failUrl=http://site.ru/pay/error&user=380999999999';

document.write(str1 + str2);
console.log(str1 + str2);
```